# Select query using PDO doesn't show all the data in the table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to display the data from my database in a table using PDO. But records are not showing. I don't have any idea what's wrong with my code.

Here is the html code:

```
<table border=15 style='font-size:0.6em;' id='result'>
  <tr>
    <th>ISSUE TYPE</th>
    <th>CREATION DATE</th>
    <th>SITE</th>
    <th>VENDOR NAME</th>
    <th>INVOICE DATE</th>
    <th>INVOICE NUMBER</th>
    <th>PART NUMBER</th>
    <th>PO</th>
    <th>RR</th>
    <th>CURRENCY</th>
    <th>INVOICE AMOUNT</th>
    <th>ISSUES</th>
    <th>PERSON IN CHARGE</th>
    <th>PIC COMMENTS</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
```

And here's my PHP code to display the data in the table:

```
<?php 

$invtxt = $_POST['InvNumbTxt'];
$dbh=db_connect();         
$sql="SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

  echo"<form name='update' method='POST'><tr class=output2>";
  echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[5]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[6]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[7]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[8]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[9]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[10]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[11]</td>";
  echo "<td>$row[12]</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='pic' value='$row[17]'></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='comt' value='$row[18]'></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='stat' value='$row[19]'></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='submit' name='save_btn' value='&diams; SAVE &diams;' style='font-size:1em;'/></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='idtxt' value='$row[0]'/></td>";
  echo "</tr></form>"; 
} 
$dbh=null;

?>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: `$stmt>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` should use `->`

Comment: use **SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice where invtxt='$invtxt'**

Comment: put you `form` outside of while and use `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ` in while loop.

Comment: it's not possible because i want to display all the data from my database

Comment: enable error reporting to test any fatal error or something like in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have type error also,

change this

`while($row = $stmt>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

to

`while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

modify your `while` loop like below,

`<form>` value should not be inside loop.

```
    echo"<form name='update' method='POST'>";

    while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

    echo "<tr class=output2>";
    echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[5]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[6]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[7]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[8]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[9]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[10]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[11]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[12]."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='pic' value='".$row[12]."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='comt' value='".$row[18]."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='stat' value='".$row[19]."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='save_btn' value='&diams; SAVE &diams;' style='font-size:1em;'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='idtxt' value='".$row[0]."'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    echo '</form>';
    $dbh=null;

?>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `$stmt>fetchAll`

Comment: @Suchit by mistake. corrected it. I meant to say he has issue with `echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";`

Comment: you need to put tr inside the while loop only form should be outside if he need only one form then.

Comment: Thanks but it displayed rows without the data.

Comment: @Klowie instead of `$row[1]` try `$row['YOUR_FIELD_NAME']`. replace with your field name

Comment: @Klowie glad it helped you. consider accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @anto.nishanth I have a problem in my search button. it's the same data and process in the above question. Whenever I search a particular data in the search textbox, data is added on my table instead of displaying only the specific data I've searched.

Comment: I already accepted your answer. I did'nt reverted it. I don't know why it keeps on reverting.

Comment: yes on the same page. At first, I displayed the data. Then I have a search function to display a specific data on the table

Comment: if(isset($_POST['search_btn']))

{
 $row = null; 

 if(empty($_POST['InvNumbTxt']))
 {
 echo '<h3>*Please input invoice number!</h3>';
 }
 else
 {
 $invtxt = $_POST['InvNumbTxt'];
 $dbh=db_connect();         
 $sql1="SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE Invoice_Number='".$invtxt."'";
 $stmt1=$dbh->prepare($sql1); 
 $stmt1->execute();

Comment: @Klowie I hope that will have different set of codes, why cant you raise a new question with related code snippets?

Comment: @Klowie my guess you might have same name for the search button as same as submit button `name='save_btn'`

Comment: It seems like stackoverflow banned me for 2 days in asking question. So sad :(

Comment: @Klowie instead of `name='save_btn'` on your search button change it to `name='search_btn'`

Comment: The name of my search button is search_btn. So i Think there's no problem with the button.

Comment: @Klowie sorry to say I cant guess if dont see your elaborated code.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
while($row = $stmt>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

to:

```
while($row = $stmt>fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

PDO Statement's fetchall method does what it says on the tin, it grabs the entire result set in one hit. PDO Statement's fetch method just grabs the next row of the result set.

Comment: thanks. It displayed 4 rows without the data. How come it didn't able to read the data on my database?

Comment: If you do the select query direct against the database using something like PHPMyAdmin, how many rows are found (also is what is returned what you're expecting to get)?